# What is the SQL Server equivalent of INET_ATON

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005

As the question says what is the SQL Server equivalent of `INET_ATON` from mySql. The reason I need this is because i imported a IP data base from http://ipinfodb.com/ip_database.php into SQL Server 2005 and would like to query the table now. But based on their examples I am not sure how to do that.

> [INET_ATON(expr)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton)
>
> Given the dotted-quad representation
>   of a network address as a string,
>   returns an integer that represents the
>   numeric value of the address.
>   Addresses may be 4- or 8-byte
>   addresses.
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT INET_ATON('209.207.224.40');
>         -> 3520061480
> ```

Comment: See similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695568/porting-from-mysql-to-t-sql-any-inet-aton-equivalent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at these [stored procedure examples](http://www.imacdonald.co.uk/2008/06/06/ip-to-numeric/) for achieving this

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ipStringToInt 
( 
    @ip CHAR(15) 
) 
RETURNS INT 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @rv INT, 
        @o1 INT, 
        @o2 INT, 
        @o3 INT, 
        @o4 INT, 
        @base INT 

    SELECT 
        @o1 = CONVERT(INT, PARSENAME(@ip, 4)), 
        @o2 = CONVERT(INT, PARSENAME(@ip, 3)), 
        @o3 = CONVERT(INT, PARSENAME(@ip, 2)), 
        @o4 = CONVERT(INT, PARSENAME(@ip, 1)) 

    IF (@o1 BETWEEN 0 AND 255) 
        AND (@o2 BETWEEN 0 AND 255) 
        AND (@o3 BETWEEN 0 AND 255) 
        AND (@o4 BETWEEN 0 AND 255) 
    BEGIN      
        SELECT @base = CASE 
            WHEN @o1 < 128 THEN 
                (@o1 * 16777216) 
            ELSE 
                -(256 - @o1) * 16777216 
            END 

        SET @rv = @base +  
            (@o2 * 65536) +  
            (@o3 * 256) + 
            (@o4) 
    END 
    ELSE 
        SET @rv = -1 
    RETURN @rv 
END
```

Example usage

```
INSERT mytable VALUES(dbo.ipStringToInt('1.2.3.4'))
```

If you want to reverse that and turn an integer into a dotted-quad, try this

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ipIntToString 
( 
    @ip bigINT 
) 
RETURNS CHAR(15) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @o1 bigINT, 
        @o2 bigINT, 
        @o3 bigINT, 
        @o4 bigINT 

    IF ABS(@ip) > 4294967295 
        RETURN '255.255.255.255' 

    SET @o1 = @ip / 16777216 

    IF @o1 = 0 
        SELECT @o1 = 255, @ip = @ip + 16777216 

    ELSE IF @o1 < 0 
    BEGIN 
        IF @ip % 16777216 = 0 
            SET @o1 = @o1 + 256 
        ELSE 
        BEGIN 
            SET @o1 = @o1 + 255 
            IF @o1 = 128 
                SET @ip = @ip + 2147483648 
            ELSE 
                SET @ip = @ip + (16777216 * (256 - @o1)) 
        END 
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        SET @ip = @ip - (16777216 * @o1) 
    END 

    SET @ip = @ip % 16777216 
    SET @o2 = @ip / 65536 
    SET @ip = @ip % 65536 
    SET @o3 = @ip / 256 
    SET @ip = @ip % 256 
    SET @o4 = @ip 

    RETURN 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @o1) + '.' + 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @o2) + '.' + 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @o3) + '.' + 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @o4) 
END
```

Comment: what can I use to convert that number back to an ip though?

Comment: it's covered in the linked article

Comment: In my case had to switch RETURNS, "@rv" and "@o1" to BIGINT, as I've have been getting "overflown int" at some IP combinations.

Answer (score 3):

I came here looking for the same, and applied Paul Dixon's solution.

However, I noticed that we also have some IPv6 addresses, so I changed it a little bit:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ip2int]
(
    @ip VARCHAR(15) 
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @rv INT, 
        @o1 INT, 
        @o2 INT, 
        @o3 INT, 
        @o4 INT, 
        @base INT 

IF ISNUMERIC(PARSENAME(@ip, 4) + '.0e0') =0 OR ISNUMERIC(PARSENAME(@ip, 3) + '.0e0') =0 OR ISNUMERIC(PARSENAME(@ip, 2) + '.0e0') =0 OR ISNUMERIC(PARSENAME(@ip, 1) + '.0e0') =0
    BEGIN
        set @rv = -2
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @o1 = CONVERT(INT, PARSENAME(@ip, 4)), 
        @o2 = CONVERT(INT, PARSENAME(@ip, 3)), 
        @o3 = CONVERT(INT, PARSENAME(@ip, 2)), 
        @o4 = CONVERT(INT, PARSENAME(@ip, 1)) 

    IF (@o1 BETWEEN 0 AND 255) 
        AND (@o2 BETWEEN 0 AND 255) 
        AND (@o3 BETWEEN 0 AND 255) 
        AND (@o4 BETWEEN 0 AND 255) 
    BEGIN      
        SELECT @base = CASE 
            WHEN @o1 < 128 THEN 
                (@o1 * 16777216) 
            ELSE 
                -(256 - @o1) * 16777216 
            END 

        SET @rv = @base +  
            (@o2 * 65536) +  
            (@o3 * 256) + 
            (@o4) 
    END 
    ELSE 
        SET @rv = -1 
    END
    RETURN @rv 

END
```

Comment: you claimed your stored procedure supports ipv6 but your param @ip only supports 15 characters.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in function to do this in MSSQL, however the formula for converting A.B.C.D to an IP Number is:

IP Number = A x (256*256*256) + B x (256*256) + C x 256 + D

I may have the sql functions written somewhere to do this, ill have a look.