# Sorting IP addresses in TSQL

Tags: t-sql, sorting

I need my IP list sorted. Problem is that i want them sorted after the value in the first part, then second part and so on.

```
MYTABLE

DATA
20.1.2.1
100.1.1.1
20.1.10.1
80.8.8.8
```

This code doesn't order the IP correct

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE ORDER BY DATA
```

I was hoping to get something like this:

```
20.1.2.1
20.1.10.1
80.8.8.8
100.1.1.1
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690101/storing-ip-addresses-in-microsoft-sql-server

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although it wasn't designed for IP addresses, you can use `PARSENAME` to divide a string into sections by splitting on the period.

I see though that you have IP addresses with a colon instead of a period, so you would just need to replace all your colons with a period.

Thus, you could do:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY CAST(PARSENAME(REPLACE(Data, ':', '.'), 4) as int),
    CAST(PARSENAME(REPLACE(Data, ':', '.'), 3) as int),
    CAST(PARSENAME(REPLACE(Data, ':', '.'), 2) as int),
    CAST(PARSENAME(REPLACE(Data, ':', '.'), 1) as int)
```

You can throw this in Query Analyzer to confirm it works:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT '20:1:2:1' AS Data UNION
    SELECT '100:1:1:1' UNION
    SELECT '20:1:10:1' UNION
    SELECT '80:8:8:8'
) X
ORDER BY CAST(PARSENAME(REPLACE(Data, ':', '.'), 4) as int),
    CAST(PARSENAME(REPLACE(Data, ':', '.'), 3) as int),
    CAST(PARSENAME(REPLACE(Data, ':', '.'), 2) as int),
    CAST(PARSENAME(REPLACE(Data, ':', '.'), 1) as int)
```

See the [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, Saved me loads of time.

Comment: This works as long as your database server is MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

This is something you'd use the INET_ATON() function in MySQL, while that doesn't exist for T-SQL, [see this question for examples of how it can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695568/porting-from-mysql-to-t-sql-any-inet-aton-equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

Store the IP addresses as plain 32-bit integers (it's guaranteed they fit) and sort those. For IPv6 convert to a 128-bit integer instead.