# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value error

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database

I am keep getting this error after added inner join

```
SELECT 
   character.dbo.user_character.character_name,
   character.dbo.user_character.wLevel,
   character.dbo.user_character.byPCClass,
   character.dbo.user_character.wMapIndex,
   character.dbo.user_character.wPosX,
   character.dbo.user_character.wPosY,
   ban_info.dbo.account_login.ip
FROM
   character.dbo.user_character
INNER JOIN ban_info.dbo.account_login ON (character.dbo.user_character.wPosY=ban_info.dbo.account_login.ip)
WHERE (character.dbo.user_character.user_no='12100601280065')
```

Error

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '127.0.0.1' to data type int.

How can I FIX IT>?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this; http://daipratt.co.uk/mysql-store-ip-address/. . It requires some tweaking to store an IP Address.

Comment: I am using mssql, not mysql

Comment: Simple searching will get you very far.... [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690101/storing-ip-addresses-in-microsoft-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is just comparing an Ip address (that is not an integer) stored on `ban_info.dbo.account_login.ip` by integer value stored on `character.dbo.user_character.wPosY` in following line :

```
INNER JOIN ban_info.dbo.account_login ON (character.dbo.user_character.wPosY = ban_info.dbo.account_login.ip)
```

Comment: Okay, I changed it, and seems it fixed the problem, I changed the wPosY to varchar and it's work now, no errors, but it gives me now blank row

Comment: @user2875727 Because you are comparing two mismatched values
for example 52 is not equal by 192.168.0.12 .

Comment: ah, got it, so I tried to do compare between two same lines like        ban_info.dbo.account_login.ip=ban_info.dbo.account_login.ip              and now for all the rows it show me the first ip that in the columns

Answer (score 0):

I think you should convert IP address to int in php (or db) and then compare it.
There is function [ip2long()](https://www.php.net/ip2long) in PHP