# SQL Server : selecting Ips form Ips range

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, database

I'm quite new to SQL and I kind off hit the wall with this:

I have quite simple SQL query but I need to modify that that query to select only `IP_ADDRESS` from IPs range `100.64.0.0 – 100.127.255.255` and `10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255`. I know that I need to use regexp for that but do not know how?  Can You help me?

Original query:

```
SELECT 
    sal.IP_ADDRESS, sal.COUNTRY_CODE, sal.EVENT_ID, p.name, p.PARTNER_ID
FROM 
    EVENTS_USER.STREAM_ACCESS_LOGS sal, EVENTS_USER.STREAM_USERS su, EVENT_USER.PARTNERS p
WHERE 
    su.PARTNER_ID = p.PARTNER_ID
    AND sal.SUCESS = 'Y'
    AND sal.COUNTRY_CODE is null;
```

Could this regexp look like that?:

```
SELECT * FROM EVENTS_USER.STREAM_ACCESS_LOGS(
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace('100.64.0.0', '(\d+)', '00\1'), '0*(\d{3})', '\1')  IP_ADDRESS from dual 
UNION ALL 
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace('100.127.255.255', '(\d+)', '00\1'), '0*(\d{3})', '\1') from dual
) ORDER BY IP_ADDRESS;
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support Regex, unless it's a new feature in 2016 that I don't know about yet.   Look into using PARSENAME().

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick respons. This my first larger SQL query than just simple SELECT * FROM ;) thanks for advise about bad habits, I will try to learn from that and do not make same mistake twice thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL we have the [`INET_ATON()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton), which converts an address into a 32-bit integer. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/695642/1255289) to another question (not sure if this qualifies as a duplicate?) provides some equivalent SQL Server code:

```
create function INET_ATON (@addr varchar(15))
returns bigint
with schemabinding
as
begin
  return
    cast(parsename(@addr, 4) as bigint) * 16777216 +
    cast(parsename(@addr, 3) as bigint) * 65536 +
    cast(parsename(@addr, 2) as bigint) * 256 +
    cast(parsename(@addr, 1) as bigint)
end
```

You could then add this into your query:

```
SELECT 
    sal.IP_ADDRESS, sal.COUNTRY_CODE, sal.EVENT_ID, p.name, p.PARTNER_ID
FROM 
    EVENTS_USER.STREAM_ACCESS_LOGS sal, EVENTS_USER.STREAM_USERS su, EVENT_USER.PARTNERS p
WHERE 
    su.PARTNER_ID = p.PARTNER_ID
    AND sal.SUCESS = 'Y'
    AND sal.COUNTRY_CODE is null
    AND (
        INET_ATON(sal.IP_ADDRESS) BETWEEN INET_ATON("100.64.0.0") AND INET_ATON("100.127.255.255") OR
        INET_ATON(sal.IP_ADDRESS) BETWEEN INET_ATON("10.0.0.0") AND INET_ATON("10.255.255.255")
    )
```